# Problem with SQL Server connection string: trustServerCertificate=true is being interpreted as trustServerCerticate=false;

Tags: java, sql-server

We're experiencing issues with a connection string used in an app that has recently been upgraded to use Java 17.

The string is as follows:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;databaseName=[mydb];encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true

When the app. is brought up, we get the following error:

```
2023-08-22 12:09:17.746[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10768[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mcom.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m HikariPool-2 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: "encrypt" property is set to "true" and "trustServerCertificate" property is set to "false" but the driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption: Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. ClientConnectionId:ae5d4fb9-9813-4ba6-b5d2-c3895eabe0db
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3957)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1950)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3477)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:3097)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2939)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1801)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1241)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.lambda
```

It looks like the driver thinks the trustServerCertificate property has been set to "false" whereas the connection string clearly defines it as true. It feels like something , somewhere is overriding this value but we are struggling to nail it down. Any help would be gratefully received.

The app. is being maintained in STS v4.18.1 and using the Eclipse Adoptium JDK, jdk-17.0.8.7-hotspot. We have also configured the SQLServerDialect as SQLServer2012Dialect and we are using version 12.3.0.jre17-preview of the SQL Server driver. We have also tried version 12.4.0.jre11 of the Driver to no avail. HikariCP is at 4.0.3 and we use Hibernate 5.6.12 and Spring Boot 2.7.5.

Many thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint in SQLServerDriver or wherever to see if the string is still the same or something changed it?

Comment: All of the example connection strings I am finding have a trailing semicolon on the last property: `trustServerCertificate=true;`

Comment: Recent versions of the ODBC/JDBC/SqlClient drivers added a new `hostNameInCertificate` property for when the CN/Subject of the SQL Server certificate doesn't actually match the host name used in the connection URI. Have you tried setting that?

Comment: @siggemannen I've just tried that, thanks: nothing jumps out but I may have missed something in the 1000s line of code

Comment: @RobertHarvey unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm having difficulty identifying which certificate to use. I will need to go off to the SQL Server resources and find out how to do that. Thanks